# Unknown class in interface builder file, when copying storyboard

Tags: ios, class

I imported my storyboard from another app I worked on, however now on every view the module is set to none, and when I run the project I get the following error:

```
Unknown class _TtC9Gym_Amigo26SplashScreenViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

and

```
Could not load the "GRADIENT LONG RECTANGLE.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.wal******.***-*****"
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is pretend that you just created this storyboard, and configure it as you would if you had just created it. Thus:

- For the first error, locate e.g. the splash screen view controller in the storyboard and re-enter its class in its Identity inspector (Amigo26SplashScreenViewController). When you press Return, the module will be entered and the class will become known to the storyboard.
- For the second error, add the "GRADIENT LONG RECTANGLE.png" image to your project. In the storyboard, set it as the image of this image view (or whatever it is).

Answer (score 0):

You coppy only the storyboard file in your project so when you build the project xcode couldn't find the image **"GRADIENT LONG RECTANGLE.png"** in one of your uiimageView. So set this image to concern image view. So your one error will be gone.

Now for the second error there is an unknown class in your splash screen interface builder.

So just find out that class and look for its declaration in your project. If it is not declared, declare it or delete the splash screen and add your own from the scratch.